# Is the limit of the empty diagram considered a product?

Tags: category-theory

It is a theorem on the stacks project that if a category $\mathcal{C}$ has finite products and equalizers then it has a terminal object, this theorem is at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04AS.

But the category $\mathbb{Z}$ considered as a totally ordered set has all finite products which are given by taking the minimal element, and it vacuously have all equalizers, but has no final object. What is going wrong here?

Comment: It seems to have finite limits but it doesn't: otherwise, it would have a final object.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Unless the limit of the empty diagram is considered a product then $\mathbb{Z}$ certainly has finite products and equalizers, which should imply that it has a final object. Is it standard to consider the limit of the empty diagram to be a product?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the question, and really ought to be the main body of your question. But yes, I think that theorem assumes that the empty product is a product (as is a one-element product, but that trivially exists in all categories.)

Comment: @ufabao Yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}$ does not, in fact, have finite limits: what's the limit of the empty diagram?

(The empty diagram counts as a finite diagram, so when we say that a category has finite limits it has to apply to the empty diagram too.)

Comment: ... so we mend this by adding an element $+\infty$ that plays the role of minimume of the empty set, and voila, there's the final object

Comment: But is the limit of the empty diagram considered a product? I thought about this but it seems in categories for the working mathematician a product is required to have at least 2 objects in the diagram

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Shouldn't the direct limit of the empty set be $-\infty?$ The direct limit of a non-empty set is the maximum, and you need the a limit $\alpha$ to have a unique $\alpha\to x$ for each object $x.$ So, assuming the usual, $x\leq y$ meaning $x\to y$, you need an absolute minimum.

Comment: @ufabao I am unaware of any source which doesn't consider the empty diagram a diagram. I don't have CFTWM on hand, but I'm pretty confident that it allows the empty diagram too.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Right, but what i'm asking is if the limit of the empty diagram is considered a product. MacClane's definition of product requires that the indexing category have at least two objects, and those objects have no maps between them.

Comment: @ufabao I am surprised to hear that, and would consider that restricted definition nonstandard. I'm not a category theorist, but it seems that the stacks project agrees with me on this.

Comment: @ufabao The definition of "a category with finite products" in CWM (the second edition, at least) explicitly mentions that this includes the terminal object (see page 72).